# Redefined parameter loses its inferred type when in another block

Tags: typescript

As example, I'll use a function that receive a argument and returns a function that always returns a number. I'll have two possible results:

- if I convert the argument in the first block, the return type will get lost

  ```
  // foo(bar: string | number) => () => string | number

  function foo(bar: string | number) {
      bar = +bar;

      return function () {
          return bar;
      }
  }
  ```
- if I convert the argument in the second block, the return type will
  be inferred properly:

  ```
  // foo2(bar2: string | number) => () => number

  function foo2(bar2: string | number) {
      return function () {
          return +bar2;
      }
  }
  ```

Why does the type of a redefined parameter get lost?

Comment: See [Microsoft/TypeScript #9998: Trade-offs in Control Flow Analysis](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The TypeScript compiler uses [control flow based type analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) to infer narrower types of variables.  As you note, when you take `bar: string | number` and set it to `+bar`, the value of `bar` will definitely be a `number` immediately afterward.  For the remainder of the scope, unless you redefine `bar` again, TypeScript will know that `bar` is a `number`.

Except when it doesn't.  Returning the anonymous function `function(){return bar;}` introduces a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) where the value of `bar` will remain unexamined indefinitely until such time as that returned function is called.  At this point, the TypeScript compiler gives up.  It doesn't know if someone will change the value of `bar` to a `string` before that function is called, so it doesn't keep the narrowed type within the clousre.

"Wait", you might say, "by inspection I can see that nothing can happen to the value of `bar` after I return that function, so it's always a `number` forever."  And you're probably right.  Unfortunately the compiler is not as smart as you, and giving up when encountering a closure is just one of many heuristics used to keep the problem of control-flow analysis tractable.

There is an excellent issue in GitHub about the difficulty with getting control-flow analysis "right": [Microsoft/TypeScript #9998: Trade-offs in Control Flow Analysis](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998). There are many cases where the compiler can be fooled into either failing to narrow a type (incompleteness) or over-narrowing a type (unsoundness).  That's just the way it is, at least until we reach the [technological singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technological_singularity).