# typescript has different types for the same variable in the same scope

Tags: typescript

`value` here has two different types.
one is `string` and the other is `string | string[]`

```
function getValue(value: string | (()=>string)):void{}

function test(value: string | string[]): void{

 if(value instanceof Array){
   return
 }
 
  // commenting out this line resolve the issue, but I don't know why?
  // TS consider `value` here as string | string[], but it should be string only
  value = 'string'

  // `value` here is string
  getValue(value)

  // but here is string | string[]
  getValue(()=>value)
}
```

[typescript play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQGoEMA2JUAUAbrvgFyIDOUATjGMogD6IEECUAvAHzV0Pt2ZInBgATAN4BfAFAzQkWAkRRU1YqVQU+9Rix0MA2gF0hiEeIlzEMYBryobYalkio4wRAEEaNLAE92K0QQmnQQGjAZRFlEaMQAegTECDgAWzTUMFgGRDgQKBUACxhKRBx6RzDKOBwiRygix1LKfAAaRAAjAsQASUQxBAByQoBrMDgAd0RJov8AfnikxAAVAGUUhEpxVBpEAAMSB33EJrDELDKDPSpaXRMO7sKYQsoi-JwxLsdrvLAcfzxI74RCcRBDa5DayJZKHTQnM7NK53BjxNCYTT2fDsaHLJ6nXZI278G7XExo9DYBxsLjcYGoHFSIA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48450317/redefined-parameter-loses-its-inferred-type-when-in-another-block), `value` in the closure `getValue(() => value)` breaks the [control-flow-based-type-analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#control-flow-based-type-analysis).

There are two solutions:

1. Declare a local variable like `_value` with `string` value.

```
function getValue(value: string | (() => string)): void { }


function test(value: string | string[]): void {
  let _value = 'string'
  if (typeof value === 'string') {
    getValue(value)
    getValue(() => _value)
  } else {
    // value is string[] type here
    console.log(value)
  }
}
```

2. Use type assertion

```
function getValue(value: string | (() => string)): void { }


function test(value: string | string[]): void {
  value = 'string'
  if (typeof value === 'string') {
    getValue(value)
    getValue(() => value as string)
  } else {
    // value is string[] type here
    console.log(value)
  }
}
```

Comment: didn't work, when you set `value = 'string` before `if(typeof value === 'string')`  [play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQGoEMA2JUAUAbrvgFyIDOUATjGMogD6IEECUAvAHzV0Pt2ZInBgATAN4BfAFBzQkWAkRRU1YqVQU+9Rix0MA2gF0hiEeIlzE5zZ0QByA8gczEMYASgBPAA6o4YFs8VEROcMdnB3YrGxs0TE0NEPY3OITsELYubhIUtylEVBxKUNibAHoK4Px3SipaXRMVP1CAC1QaVDTECARKOBxUADocOGRk-FTEWSkgA)

Comment: @Sheldeeb Updated anwser.